# php foreach with javascript script

Tags: javascript, php, foreach

I have a php foreach loop which I would like to use to create 5 charts based on the data that i feed into the script. The problem that I cant figure out is that at the moment my chart is visible only at the last loop and is not visible on the first, second, third.

I tried to do something like `var chart<?=$row['id'];?>=...` to no avail. How can I get my charts to appear with the correct data in the foreach loop?

```
<? foreach($articles as $row):?>
<div id='chart-<?=$row['id'];?>' style='width: 1110px; height: 250px;'></div>
    <script>
        var chart1 = new Charts.LineChart('chart-<?=$row['id'];?>', {
          dot_color: "#855541",
          area_color: "#855541",
          line_color: "#855541",
          line_width: 1,
          show_grid: false,
          label_max: false,
          label_min: false
        });
        chart1.add_line({
          data: [<?=$row['chart'];?>]
        });
        chart1.draw();
    </script>
  <?endforeach;?>
```

Comment: We need to see the loop.

Comment: Where is this `foreach` loop? Please edit your question to show how you are currently doing it.

Comment: I think all the `<?=` should be replaced with `<?php echo ` ?

Comment: I've added the foreach loop. @user007 I'm using short tags.

Comment: @user007 php 5.3 and greater supports <?= regardless of ini settings

Comment: is chart1 being overwritten every time php loop iterate?
even if u r putting it into diff div, all js vars will occupy same space since ur declaring it as global.

Comment: @MohammedJoraid that's likely true. After all the "name" of the var will be overwritten each time it seems.

Comment: Yes it is, unfortunately. I don't know how to do it so that the charts do not get overwritten.

Comment: @Ando see the answers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to Mohammed's comment, try changing the JavaScript variable name each time.

```
<? foreach($articles as $row):?>
<div id='chart-<?=$row['id'];?>' style='width: 1110px; height: 250px;'></div>
    <script>
        var chart<?=$row['id'];?> = new Charts.LineChart('chart-<?=$row['id'];?>', {
          dot_color: "#855541",
          area_color: "#855541",
          line_color: "#855541",
          line_width: 1,
          show_grid: false,
          label_max: false,
          label_min: false
        });
        chart<?=$row['id'];?>.add_line({
          data: [<?=$row['chart'];?>]
        });
        chart<?=$row['id'];?>.draw();
    </script>
  <?endforeach;?>
```

Comment: Thanks Stanyer and Mohammed for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

`chart1` is being overwritten every time php loop iterates.

Even if u r putting it into diff div, all js vars will occupy same space since ur declaring it as global.

One way to do it is to define different variables for each iteration either by assigning a different var name, or adding all vars into an array and later loop thru it and execute all.

As in the other answers, change

```
var chart1 = ...
```

to something like:

```
var chart_<?=$row['id']?> =
```

it will be e.g. `chart_1`, `chart_2`, `chart_3` ...etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<? $i = 1; foreach($articles as $row):?>
<div id='chart-<?=$row['id'];?>' style='width: 1110px; height: 250px;'></div>
    <script>
        var chart<?=$i; ?> = new Charts.LineChart('chart-<?=$row['id'];?>', {
          dot_color: "#855541",
          area_color: "#855541",
          line_color: "#855541",
          line_width: 1,
          show_grid: false,
          label_max: false,
          label_min: false
        });
        chart<?=$i; ?>.add_line({
          data: [<?=$row['chart'];?>]
        });
        chart<?=$i; ?>.draw();

    </script>
  <? $i++; endforeach;?>
```

Comment: There is already a unique ID, could save using an extra counter.